# timeout on installing 'mapdata'

Tags: installation, connection-timeout

typed 'install mapdata', expecting successful download, yet received timeout during download

Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen: Timeout of 60 seconds was reached

Warnung in download.packages ; Download von Paket 'mapdata' fehlgeschlagen.